# Vue state change is applied to previous focusses context

Tags: javascript, vue.js, coffeescript

So i am working on a fieldset pagination in a form i'm making with Vue. The issue i now have with my pagination is that the state-change of the visibility of the pagination controls is applied to the previous `fieldset`, instead of the current one.

My form is constructed like this:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <fieldset id="one" v-show="activePage == 'one'">
      <input />
      <pagination-ctrl @paginate="paginate" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="two" v-show="activePage == 'two'">
      <input />
      <pagination-ctrl @paginate="paginate" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="three" v-show="activePage == 'three'">
      <input />
      <pagination-ctrl @paginate="paginate" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="coffee">
  import Pagination from '@/components/Pagination.vue'
  import FormInput from '@/components/FormInput.vue'

  export default
    name: 'Form'

    data: ->
      activePage: 'one'

    components:
      'pagination-ctrl': Pagination
      'input': FormInput

    methods:
      paginate: (data) ->
        @activePage = data
</script>
```

`Pagination.vue` contains the buttons to switch between the active `fieldset` and looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="btn-group" role="button" v-on:click="paginate" ref="btn-group">
    <button class="ui-button prev" rel="prev" :disabled="disablePrev">Previous</button>
    <button class="ui-button next" rel="next" :disabled="disableNext">Next</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="coffee">
  export default
    name: 'FormControl'

    data: ->
      pages: null
      disablePrev: true
      disableNext: true

    methods:
      accumelatePages: ->
        fieldsetNode = @$refs['btn-group'].parentNode
        formNode = fieldsetNode.parentNode
        # cast fieldsets to true array in favor of HTMLNodeCollection
        @pages = Array.prototype.slice.call(formNode.getElementsByTagName('fieldset'))

      determineButtonVisibility: (item) ->
        currIndex = @pages.findIndex((node)->
          node.getAttribute('id') is item
        )

        @disablePrev =
          if currIndex > 0
            false
          else true

        @disableNext =
          if currIndex < (@pages.length - 1)
            false
          else true

      paginate: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        node = e.target

        if node.getAttribute('rel') is 'next'
          activeNode = node.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling

        if node.getAttribute('rel') is 'prev'
          activeNode = node.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling

        if activeNode?
          nodeId = activeNode.getAttribute('id')
          @$emit('paginate', nodeId)
          @determineButtonVisibility(nodeId)

    mounted: ->
      @accumelatePages()
      @determineButtonVisibility(@pages[0].getAttribute('id'))
</script>
```

The idea is that when you click a button, `determineButtonVisibility()` determines the position of the current `fieldset` in relation to the surrounding fieldsets, and sets the display of the buttons accordingly. The problem however is that this works perfectly fine, but these display-state's are applied to the fieldset you just navigated away from.

So if i click on the next button in fieldset `one`, the state-change is applied to fieldset `one` (old context) instead of fieldset `two` (new context).

Perhaps i'm now overlooking something really obvious or heading in a completely wrong direction, but i've already spent way more time on this then i actually should sho i'm kind of lost atm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you pass `activePage` as a prop from `Form.vue` into your `Pagination.vue`, and then set a watcher for when that value changes, you can have each instance of `pagination-ctrl` dynamically run `determineButtonVisibility` on change.

```
<pagination-ctrl @paginate="paginate" :activePage="activePage" />
```